# Can I enforce multiple levels for the same es lint rule. eg: error and warning for different paths

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I am looking to enforce the `no-restricted-imports` rule in my codebase for specific imports.
However, I need to throw an error for some paths and warnings for others. Looks like I cannot do it by just doing :

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
    'warn',
    {
      paths: [
        {
          name: 'd3',
          message: 'd3 would be deprecated soon, please consider moving away from it'
        }
      ] 

    },
    'error',
    {
      paths: [

        {
          name: 'moment',
          message: 'Use of moment is not allowed',
        },
     ]
  ]
```

What would be the best way to achieve this behavior?

I have already tried defining the `no-restricted-imports` rule twice, once for error and once for warning, but since its an object, it gets overridden.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in ESLint. A rule must either always `warn` or always `error`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [eslint-plugin-local](https://github.com/taskworld/eslint-plugin-local) and a small stub rule that references the `no-restricted-imports` rule directly from the eslint package could potentially get this working for you.

Not elegant by any stretch, but seems like it should be *possible* at least.